# whenever gem environment_variable is not being set

Tags: whenever

My config/schedule.rb file looks like this:

```
LOG_FILE = File.expand_path("#{__FILE__}/../../log/Scripts.log")

set :environment_variable, 'BACKEND_ENV'
set :environment, :production_backend
set :output, LOG_FILE

every 1.day, :at => '1:00 am' do
  rake "my_task"
end
```

When I run whenever, `output` and `environment` are set correctly, but `environment_variable` still defaults to RAILS_ENV:

```
me@my_box:~$ whenever
0 1 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/me && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake my_task --silent >> /home/me/log/Scripts.log 2>&1'
## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/javan/whenever#define-your-own-job-types) is pretty clear...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A way to change the `environment_variable` was introduced [in this commit](https://github.com/javan/whenever/commit/a5e652c02f4da24635f923d20c2e41cfed21d1b8) as :env_argument and renamed :environment_variable [in this commit](https://github.com/javan/whenever/commit/a8ba321e54b779ba4710012dd9a540d8d3912db1) and first released in version 0.8.3, so upgrading will make this feature available.

At the time of the question, 0.8.3 hadn't been released yet and I was still using 0.8.2, but I was looking at the README on Github on master branch.

Answer (score -1):

Put this in your schedule.rb file

```
env:PATH,'the/path/of/your/server/'
```